# Android: overriding an intent's option menu

Tags: android, android-camera, android-menu, android-camera-intent

Suppose i wrote a camera app by using and intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) and i notice that when i run the app, the option menu displays "Edit shortcuts", how can i add on to this option menu or completely override the option menu to my own?

Below are snippet of my code:

```
public class GPSCam extends Activity implements LocationListener,
    GpsStatus.Listener {

private Intent camIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpscam);
               ...
               ...
    this.startCamera();
}

protected void startCamera() {
              ...
    // create camera intent
    camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // define where to keep the photo
    camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    // this method will call onActivityResult() upon finishing an activity
    // i.e. image captured
    startActivityForResult(camIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                  ...
                  ...
                  ...
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the options menus of other applications. If you do not want to use another application for taking photos, you are welcome to use the `Camera` object and take photos yourself.